# MessageConversionException kafka consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have the below config of kafka stream

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: handleCatalogEvent
      bindings:
        handleCatalogEvent-in-0:
          content-type: application/json
          destination: catalog_change
          group: back-group
          consumer:
            configuration:
              json.value.type: com.test.domain.ChangeNotification
              json.fail.invalid.schema: true
            useNativeEncoding: true
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: kafka-dev.test.priv:7887
          auto-create-topics: false
          consumer-properties:
            auto.offset.reset: latest
            auto.commit.interval.ms: 1000
            specific.avro.reader: true
            auto.register.schemas: false
            key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
            value.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.KafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer
            schema.registry.url: https://schema-registry.dev.test.priv:8787
```

I have the below bean to consume the data

```
@Bean
public Consumer<Message<ChangeNotification>> handleCatalogEvent() {
    return event -> {
        log.info("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - Nature Of Change : {} - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -", event.getPayload().getNatureOfChange());
        log.info("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - PAYLOAD : {} - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -", event.getPayload().getItem());
    };
}
```

When i receive the data i get this error

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected
> character ('i' (code 105)): was expecting double-quote to start field
> name  at [Source: (String)"{idCatalog=5c824fc5b0efe060e87f056b,
> code=008, codeContext=[01], label=Spécialité PS,
> natureOfChange=INSERT, item={id=6373b315d9428a128d0ffc6c, code=kn17,
> label=string, startEffectiveDate=2022-11-15T10:25:23.21Z}}"; line: 1,
> column: 3]    at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:2391)
> ~[jackson-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:735)
> ~[jackson-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:659)
> ~[jackson-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddName(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1860)
> ~[jackson-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:734)
> ~[jackson-core-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:176)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:322)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4674)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3629)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar:2.13.1]     at
> org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter.convertFromInternal(MappingJackson2MessageConverter.java:232)
> ~[spring-messaging-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]     ... 45 common frames omitted

Comment: That JSON is not valid. All property names should be wrapped by quotes. So use quoted property names and values in JSON (recommended) or enable ```Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES```  and ```Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES``` flags in ObjectMapper

Comment: @zforgo That wouldn't work because there is equal-sign instead of colon.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at your logs, we see that you have a string payload like `{key1=value, key2=value}`.

This is not valid JSON, so you will be unable to use a JSON parser, especially not Confluent's JSONSchema parser since there is no schema to that data.

You'll need to use `StringDeserializer` for your value as well, and parse the String, or you need to fix your producer to properly use Confluent's `KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer` class